# Django view not returning return statement after Ajax-get

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I am facing a problem where after the Ajax get from the html page is executed, the following view function instruction is not executing.

Here is model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class user(models.Model):
    FB_name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    FB_link=models.URLField()
    FB_usrname=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    FB_usrID=models.IntegerField()
    FB_email=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    reg_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}{5}".format(self,self.FB_name, self.FB_link, self.FB_usrname,self.FB_usrID,self.FB_email)
```

Views.py

```
      from django.shortcuts import render
      from django.core.context_processors import csrf
      from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
      from django.views.generic import View
      from django.utils import timezone
      from django.http import HttpResponse
      from .models import user

      class login_call(View):
           def get(self, request):
                return render(request, 'login/login.html', {})


      class user_details(View):
               def get(self, request):
                    if request.GET :
                         usrID = request.GET['FB_usrID']
                         me=user.objects.filter(FB_usrID=usrID).values()
                           if not me:

                   hello=user.objects.create(FB_name=request.GET['FB_name'],
                                FB_link=request.GET['FB_link'],
                                FB_usrname=request.GET['FB_usrname'],
                                FB_usrID=request.GET['FB_usrID'],
                                FB_email=request.GET['FB_email'],
                                 reg_date=timezone.now())
                 hello.save()
                response = 0
            else:
                response = 1
        return render(request,'homepage/hom.html')
        return HttpResponse('response', content_type="application/json")




      class dashboard(View):
           def get(self, request):
              return render(request,'homepage/hom.html')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from event.views import user_details
from event.views import login_call
from event.views import dashboard


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^user_details/$',user_details.as_view()),
    url(r'',login_call.as_view()),
    url(r'^home$',dashboard.as_view()),

        ]
```

finally the GET jquery function:-

```
    $.ajax({
url:'/user_details/',
type: 'GET',
cache:'false',
data: {
    FB_usrID:'554113199893',
    FB_name:'Tharun',
    FB_link:'tharun@someshit.com',
    FB_usrname:'tharun cow',
    FB_email:'tharun@gmail.com',

    },
success:function(response){
    if(response == 0)
    {
         document.getElementById("message").innerHTML +=  "<br>Sent";
    }
    else
    {
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML +=  "<br>Fail";
    }
    },
complete:function(){},
error:function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError){}
 });
```

On click of the fucntion the data is passed to the server using ajax-get
server response:-

```
    "GET /user_details/?FB_usrID=554113199893&FB_name=Tharun&F
    B_link=tharun%40someshit.com&FB_usrname=tharun+lawrence&
    FB_email=tharun%40gmail.com HTTP/1.1" 200 11476
```

the purpose of this ajax-get is to post the Facebook user details via jquery fb api to django to store in db and authenticate to home page .

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Answer (score 3):

Your `user_details(View).get()` method starts with a `return` statement. Obviously the execution of this method **will** stop there - that's what `return` means.

Also (totally unrelated but...): a GET request **MUST NOT** modify the server's state. That's what POST / PUT / PATCH and DELETE are for.

Comment: but the issue is even that return doesn't not return the rendered page ,the page just stays ideal with the specific server response

Comment: "return doesn't not return the rendered page" : Have you checked `response` in your ajax call ?

Comment: "there isnt any response at all" : yes there is... If "Fail gets displayed", you are in the success callback, which means a response WAS returned. Just obviously not what you expect.

Comment: If you don't understand what your code is doing, you cannot "fix it" - so first learn what "return" means, then read about the HTTP protocol.

Comment: Please do `console.log(response)` and check what is the response you are getting. You will understand what exactly you are returning from your view.